# What does it mean when there is a z in front of a CSS class when there is no class item named with a z in front of it?

Tags: css, css-selectors

Can someone tell me what it means when someone puts a `z` in front of a CSS item? I do not have any class names with a z in front of them, I am the developer but someone else went in to make changes and used this in front of their class yet there is not zmedia in my coding anywhere, I checked thuroughly. So, long description, does this effect my site in anyway? If I deleted these particular class items will it effect my site? Such as

```css
.zmedia {
  /* … */
}
```

Comment: http://philipwalton.com/articles/what-no-one-told-you-about-z-index/

Comment: It means: the class begins with the letter `z`.

Comment: @Mukul215L This has nothing to do with `z-index`.

Comment: What causes you to suspect that a particular letter has significance?  When you change the class name (and update references to it accordingly), does the behavior change at all?

Comment: I guess I am not being clear at all. I am the developer and someone got into my code and tried to change things and then put a z infront of their changes but there are no classes in my coding anywhere that match that particular class

Comment: @MelJ: You're right, you're definitely not being clear.  What exactly is the problem?  That somebody modified your code?  That they created CSS directives which aren't being used?  That they didn't follow your established naming conventions?  Something else?  It's not clear at all what problem you're trying to solve here.

Comment: @MelJ can't you ask the person who modified the code why they made the change? My best guess is that they wanted to create a new css and invalidate all your existing items - a quick way is to find/replace and prefix them all with a random value.

Comment: @David Really I am just wanting to know if the class is being called upon if there is an added z in front of it. I tried to gole this question but only found z-index questions.

Comment: @MelJ: Earlier: `"but there are no classes in my coding anywhere that match that particular class"`... Then: `"I am just wanting to know if the class is being called upon"` - Sounds like you preemptively answered your own question.  If nothing in the code is referencing this directive, then nothing in the code is referencing this directive.  There's nothing special about the letter `z`.  It's a letter like any other.

Comment: @David- Thank you for your answers. I am getting used to coding and such so seeing a z in front of something was completely new to me and I was not sure if it meant anything or not. I appreciate your taking the time to answer the question. Sorry for the vaqueness

Answer (score 1):

That means nothing more than the person who created the script named the class

```
zmedia
```

`.zmedia` is a class selector.

In css everything with a dot `.` before it will be selected as a html class element, using `#` you can select an id

Answer (score 0):

It is likely just a naming convention that that developer used. I would review the rest of the code to see if you can find context that goes with that naming convention.